# TFS Branching or Moving Under Source Item

Tags: tfs, branching-strategy

I have a Team Foundation Server 2013 code structure like follows...

```
$/TeamProject/Application/AllTheCodeFiles
```

...but I'd like to refactor to have...

```
$/TeamProject/Application/Trunk/AllTheCodeFiles
```

Which will allow me to implement a branching and merging strategy moving forward by creating "Release" branches at the same level as "Trunk".

If I try to either branch or move the Application directory into Trunk, I get the error message:

> The target item $/TeamProject/Application/Trunk cannot be under the source item $/TeamProject/Application.

So, here's the process that I followed, it feels wrong and I'm guessing that there's a more efficient way of doing this.

1. Rename `$/TeamProject/Application` to `$/TeamProject/Application-trunk`
2. Create a new `$/TeamProject/Application` directory
3. Move `$/TeamProject/Application-trunk` to `$/TeamProject/Application/Trunk`

After doing this, history is associated with `$/TeamProject/Application` not `$/TeamProject/Application/Trunk`. My question is this, someone who knows more would do this in what manner?

Answer (score 7):

I've just gone through what I would do on my Test TFVC and things seem OK version history wise.

Here are the steps:

1. Start with `$/TeamProject/Application/`
2. Create a Folder at `$/TeamProject/Application/Main/`  (TFVC Convention - Trunk is SVN)
3. Check in pending changes.
4. Move all files and folders from `$/TeamProject/Application/` to `$/TeamProject/Application/Main/`
5. Check in pending changes.
6. Convert `$/TeamProject/Application/Main/` to a branch.

Here's the history of a file that was added (C58) and edited (C59) before the move (C62) and then edited (C63) after the move:

[image: History]

Comment: Dave, thanks a ton for this. I followed this process and was able to view the history of individual files like you indicated. What I am unable to do now, though, is to create a branch from $/TeamProject/Application/Main to $/TeamProject/Application/Release by changeset. If I try to do this, the only changesets I can select from $/TeamProject/Application/Main are the two commits from this process (add main and move to main).

Comment: That makes sense, because before the "move" changeset (C62), there wasn't an $/TeamProject/Application/Main.

Comment: Hi Dave, is there a workaround for this? I'm implementing branching in an old codebase and I need to create a branch from several dozen changesets before the Main branch was created. It's impossible to branch from the top-level, so I guess I'll have to download the version I want and commit that as the first changeset for the release branch - losing all the history? Is there any other way?